# PYTHON3: indentation of return values

Tags: python

This is working fine but I just don't get it why this works in this way. I think the return of True value should be inside the for loop but when I run this program it works in the opposite way. 
Can someone point out what i am misunderstanding about the indentation of return values?
Even though the solution was even shorter I wanted to know exactly about my way of coding. Please help!

```
# My attempt
def palindrome(s):
    mylist = list(s)
    j = -1
    for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1):
        if mylist[i] == mylist[j]:
            i+=1
            j-=1
            continue
        return False
    return True

# Solution answer:
def palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: It seems working...? When does not it work?

Comment: I thought return True should be inside the for loop and return False outside. What I am I misunderstanding? I just did the opposite and it works fine.

Comment: You cannot know whether it is palindrome or not inside the loop because you have to investigate from start to end. After that, out of the loop, you can finally decide!

Comment: uhhh..exactly. I gotcha. Thanks again! Very precise @GyuHyeonChoi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is called, the function can return only once.

This kind of `return` pattern is very frequently found across various programming languages. It is intuitive and efficient.

Let's say you have to check if a list of 1000 values contain only even numbers. You loop through the list and check if each element is even. **Once you find an odd number, you do not need to go further.** So you efficiently and immediately return and exit from the loop.

Here is hopefully a little bit more intuitive version of your code:

```
def palindrome(s):
    l, r = -1, 0  # left, right
    for _ in range(0, len(s) // 2 + 1):  # more efficient
        l += 1
        r -= 1
        if s[l] != s[r]:
            return False
    return True
```

Once you know the input is not palindrome, you do not need to go further.
If you did not need to stop, it is palindrome.

Comment: @peaberry Oh, really? Thank you too. Then... would you please accept it...? I want to achieve 1000 rep. ASAP... haha... @_@

Comment: Done. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

They follow the exact same rules as any other statement. What you have written means

```
def palindrome(s) {
    mylist = list(s)
    j = -1
    for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1) {
        if mylist[i] == mylist[j] {
            i+=1
            j-=1
            continue
        }
        return False
    }
    return True

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# My attempt
def palindrome(s):
    mylist = list(s)
    j = -1
    for i in range(0,len(mylist)-1):
        if mylist[i] == mylist[j]:
            i+=1
            j-=1
            continue
        return False
    return True
```

In the above code what happens is inside the for loop each time it checks if there is a mismatch in the values by comparing values by iterating over the list forwards using  variable "i" and backwards using variable "j". and returns false immediately if any one letter mismatches and so exits from the loop. And true is returned only once the for loop is completed which means no  mismatch was found in the loop

Note: i=0 gives first index, i+=1 iterates forward and j=-1 gives last index, j-=1 iterates backward

Comment: The syntax of your 'note' is out of whack. That looks like C-like syntax. This is python.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you index an array in numpy, you do it the way:

```
a[start:end:step]
```

,for every dimension. If step is negative, you return the values in inverse order. So, if step is -1, the array a[::-1] is the inverted array of a[::].

```
a[::-1] = a[::]
```

Then, if a sequence is the same as its inverse, by definition, it is a palindrome.

See: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-indexing/

Comment: Why bothering NumPy when Python too offers slice indexing?